# Libgdx: Sprite jitters on movement?

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm pretty new to the whole of LibGDX and I'm trying to build a top down RPG. I load the map in from a TMX file and render it, now I'm trying to get my guy to just move around with this simple code:

```
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
    switch(keycode){
    case Keys.DPAD_UP:
        velocity.y = speed;
        break;
    case Keys.DPAD_DOWN:
        velocity.y = -speed;
        break;
    case Keys.DPAD_LEFT:
        velocity.x = -speed;
        break;
    case Keys.DPAD_RIGHT:
        velocity.x = speed;
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

which sets the velocity which he'll apply here.

```
public void update(float delta){
    if(velocity.x > speed){
        velocity.x = speed;
    }else if (velocity.x > speed){
        velocity.x = speed;
    }
    
    if(velocity.y > speed){
        velocity.y = speed;
    }else if (velocity.y > speed){
        velocity.y = speed;
    }
    
    setX(getX() + velocity.x * delta);
    setY(getY() + velocity.y * delta);
}
```

Now this is all fine and dandy, but as soon as I begin moving it goes wrong.
Out of the blue, and completely random, the sprite sometimes just jitters back and the map gets out of place for a split second. This is extremely frustrating and I don't know why this is happening.

This is my player draw code

```
((BatchTiledMapRenderer) tiledMapRenderer).getBatch().begin();
player.draw(((BatchTiledMapRenderer) tiledMapRenderer).getBatch());
((BatchTiledMapRenderer) tiledMapRenderer).getBatch().end();
```

Comment: Can your sprites move diagonally? If not, try setting speedX to 0 when Up is pressed and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a kind of transparency color and a padding between your tiles in the tileset? That seems not to work sometimes. You could try it without.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment than an answer

Comment: Thanks for letting us know, but if it's the problem I have in my mind right now, removing the padding will fix this problem quickly.

Comment: Actually adding a padding will fix this issue instead!